# Сравнение двух массивов с помощью Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, массивы, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Есть два массива целых чисел 0 - 9, я их хочу сравнить и получить на выходе массив с разницей. То есть если в первом число больше то выдать +1 если меньше то -1 ну и для равно 0.

Реализовал это вот такой конструкцией, но мне кажется, что возможно есть более элегантное решение.

```java
int[] qst = {7, 8, 2, 0};
int[] rep = {5, 8, 5, 4};

int[] diff = IntStream
        .iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(qst.length)
        .map(i -> ((rep[i] < qst[i]) ? -1 : (rep[i] == qst[i]) ? 0 : +1))
        .toArray();
// diff = -1, 0, 1, 1
```

Может существует какой-то менее громоздкий способ, чем два тернарных оператора один в другом?

Изначально два массива - это просто два целых числа, которые я получаю с помощью взятия остатка от деления в таком вот цикле:

```java
//Конструктор класса в котором хранится число    
public SecretBlock(int numbersToArray) {
    this.arrayOfNumbers = new int[AMOUNT];
    for (int i = AMOUNT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.arrayOfNumbers[i] = numbersToArray % 10;
        numbersToArray /= 10;
    }
}
```

Также вопрос, можно ли как-то методами Stream API разрезать int на цифры?

Comment: Стримы не должны работать с состоянием. Использование `IntStream` для итерации по массиву или коллекции - это антипаттерн.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вставил ваш код в идею, она сама предложила заменить ваш код на :

```
int[] diff = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        .limit(qst.length)
        .map(i -> (compare(rep[i], qst[i])))
        .toArray();
```

Но я бы переписал вот так :

```
final int[] diff = IntStream.range(0, qst.length)
        .map(i -> compare(rep[i], qst[i]))
        .toArray();
```

чтобы избавиться от лишней операции limit.

Comment: Да так гораздо лучше, только тип массива теперь надо иметь Integer[]. У него уже эти методы переопределены.

Comment: тут используется статик метод compare, который принимает примитивы, а не обертки.

Comment: странно, у меня он просил его переопределить в классе. И заработало только так: Integer.compare(rep[i], qst[i]))

Comment: Просто compare(int, int) заработало только после статического импорта.

Answer (score 1):

В [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) есть способ идеально подходящий для этого случая:

```
int[] diff = Streams.zip(Arrays.stream(qst),
                         Arrays.stream(rep),
                         (a, b) -> a > b ? +1 : a < b ? -1 : 0)
                    .toArray();
```

Comment: Вот только у меня не получается его записать в массив так как он мне выдает массив Object[]

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `...mapToInt(x -> x).toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

```java
int[] qst = {7, 8, 2, 0};
int[] rep = {5, 8, 5, 4};
int[] diff = IntStream.range(0, qst.length)
        .map(i -> Integer.compare(rep[i], qst[i]))
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diff)); // [-1, 0, 1, 1]
```